# ASP.NET error : the underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive but in Winforms it is working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to developing in ASP.NET, the thing is that I am using the following code that I implemented on Windows Forms to consume a REST service:

```
string strJSON = txtJson.Text;

//SE CREAN LAS CREDENCIALES CASO RIS
string strUsuario = txtUsuario.Text;
string strContraseña = txtContraseña.Text;
string strCodificacionUsuario = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(strUsuario + ":" + strContraseña));

//OBTIENE LA URL DE DESTINO
string strURL = txtURL.Text;

//SE ESTABLECE LA CONEXION
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strURL);
httpWebRequest.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

//SE CREA EL ENCABEZADO DEL MENSAJE HTTP

httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + strCodificacionUsuario);
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

//SE CREA EL MENSAJE DEL JSON
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    // SE ENVIA EL MENSAJE A LA DIRECCION
    streamWriter.Write(strJSON);
}

//SE OBTIENE LA RESPUESTA DE MOVIMIENTOS
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    //LEE LA RESPUESTA
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

    //LA ADICIONA AL LOG
    txtRespuesta.Text = "Respuesta TRUE Normal: " + result;
}
```

The issue that I am getting is when I consume the service with ASP.NET - I get the following error:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive

but when I consume the REST service from my Winforms app, it works correctly.

How can I solve this error? Why does it work with Winforms, but not with ASP.NET ? Is it possible that I must configure something with a digital certificate?

Thank you for your answer and understanding,